# Firefox ... SVG ... Underline ... how for christ's sake?

Tags: firefox, svg

Anything I tried failed so far to get Firefox to underline some text.

According to Google-results this issue is known and documented for more than five years ... that just can't be true ... what is going on?

Someone knows any consitently working workaround or maybe even a reason as to why they didn't fix it yet!? ... I am very curious about that

Comment: What have you tried? What results did you get? What results did you want? Where is it documented that this has been an issue for more than 5 years?

Comment: CSS-styles inline and within <style>-Tags, the documented attribute with the documented value, the results I got where 'no underlining' and for the rest just type the keywords in Google.

Comment: In case of future viewers of this, as of 25.0.1 this works. No idea when it was changed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In *my* Firefox, a `ForeignObject` text within an SVG gets perfectly underlined if I include it in the right tags:

`<html:u>blub</html:u>`

... having declared html as a namespace in the svg, sample code looks like this:

```
<div style="border:solid black 2px;">
<svg:svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
  xmlns:html="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
  width="300" height="50" > 
 <foreignObject width="80" height="50">
   <html:u>blub</html:u>
 </foreignObject>
</svg:svg>
</div>
```

Would that be a solution for you?

Comment: Definitley looks interesting! Thanks!

Comment: This nearly does the job ... do you know how to integrate it seamless into a <text>- or <tspan>-section. B/c know it's located (0,0) by default, and I have to relocate it explicetly. Is it possible to just have Text in <text> and underline one word using this method?

Comment: Now it seems like Google Chrome doesn't like this solution.

Comment: Your sample code works after getting rid of the ':svg'-es. But in Chrome the blob vanishes after putting it within <g><text> ... </text></g>.

Comment: As far as I know (see <http://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/extend.html#ForeignObjectElement>), `foreignObject` s are located absolutely via `top`/`left`. Maybe you must take care to provide enough space for the display of this object by setting height and width of the parent node?

Comment: Probably depends on your doctype, whether you're using the HTML5 parser, how it's being served, etc.

Answer (score 3):

Underlines on text in SVG, as well as other text decoration, is not supported in Firefox yet, that is true.  ([Bug 317196](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=317196) attests to that.)  There is a plan to rework the SVG text layout code over the next few months, the result of which should be (among other things) underlines working.

In the meantime, if you really need them (and cannot draw them manually with a `<line>`, because for example you don't know the text metrics), you could use a `<foreignObject>` to include some HTML content with underlines.

Comment: foreignObject sounds interesting. I'll check it out ... thanks!

Comment: You know, it's failures to include simple pieces of functionality like this that wastes so much development time. If you're gonna support a feature, support it properly oh holier than thou Mozilla Project. Right, back to implementing a lengthy foreignObject workaround. Life is too short for this.