# Firefox, SVG, text-decoration

Tags: firefox, svg

### Consider the following snippet of code:

```
<text style="text-decoration:underline;"> Underline </text>
```

It renders properly for me in both the latest version of Chrome & Safari; however, it fails in the latest version of Firefox.

### Question:

- if text-decoration not part of the SVG standard?

or

- does Firefox not support the entirety of SVG?

and lastly:

- how do I get underline / strike through / over line in firefox SVG text given the above?

Thanks!

### EDIT

Hmm, does https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=317196 confirm that Firefox, in 2012, does not support SVG underline? :-)

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4645551/firefox-svg-underline-how-for-christs-sake? There is a workaround there ...

Comment: Firefox has supported underline since 2013

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The bug you linked to is it.

And no one supports "the entirety of SVG" (at least of SVG 1.1).  Chances are, no one ever will.

Comment: Why will no one ever fully support SVG1.1?  Is there a technology in the works or already existing that could conceivably replace SVG? Because, if not, never is a *long* time.

Comment: Because parts of SVG 1.1 contradict other specs (e.g. CSS).  So UAs have to choose whether to support SVG 1.1 or CSS, and they would tend to choose CSS.