# Text Sprite styling

Tags: css, extjs, extjs4, extjs4.1

Is there some way to define a text [sprite](http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-1/#!/api/Ext.draw.Sprite) with some more style options then just size and font as shown in the example?

```
{
    type: "text",
    text: "Hello, Sprite!",
    fill: "green",
    font: "18px monospace"
}
```

Specifically, I want to make it bold or underlined.

I tried a `style` config like this:

```
style: {
    'text-decoration': 'underline'
}
```

I also tried setting it in the font config like this:

```
font: "underline 18px monospace"
```

Neither worked.

This sentence from the `Ext.draw.Sprite#font` config [in the docs](http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-1/#!/api/Ext.draw.Sprite-cfg-font) sounded promising but it is pretty cryptic:

> Uses the same syntax as the CSS font parameter

I've been googling around for **the** CSS font parameter and haven't found much of use. Maybe if someone knows what that means they can shed some light on this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `font` css attribute will let you specify bold and italics, but underline is set using the `text-decoration` attribute.  You'll need to use a style config:

```
{
    type: "text",
    text: "Hello, Sprite!",
    fill: "green",
    font: "bold 18px monospace",
    style: {
        textDecoration: "underline"
    }
}
```

**Working demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/gilly3/WSQv9/.
Tested in Chrome and IE9.  [Firefox doesn't yet support underline in SVG](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10906380/firefox-svg-text-decoration).

For reference, here is the font parameter definition:
[MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/ms530756(v=vs.85).aspx)
[MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/font)

Answer (score 2):

I've never used extjs, but it looks like SVG to me. Unfortunately Firefox doesn't support `text-decoration` attribute on svg elements, so perhaps you are testing in Firefox but in Chrome it might be displaying fine with your `style` attribute.

The workaround for this would be drawing the underline manually with a `line` element. It is not difficult with javascript but I would have no idea of how to accomplish this the extjs way.

Comment: I second this solution because of browser compatibility issues with 'text-decoration'.