# Text decoration of SVG tspan

Tags: svg, cross-browser, typography, tspan

I'm seeing inconsistent rendering of SVG `<tspan>` elements in regards to text-decoration.

Using this simple testcase:

```
<text font-family="Helvetica" x="0" y="50" font-size="30" text-decoration='underline overline'>
  outer text
  <tspan font-size="15" text-decoration="overline">tspan w. overline</tspan>
</text>
```

### WebKit (~Safari 8)

[image]

### Firefox (37)

[image]

### Internet Explorer (11)

[image]

[The section on text decoration](http://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/text.html#TextDecorationProperties) doesn't seem to explain much.

> Since ‘text-decoration’ is specified on the ‘text’ element, all text
>   within the ‘text’ element has its underline rendered with the same
>   fill and stroke properties as exist on the ‘text’ element (i.e., blue
>   fill, red stroke), even though the various words have different fill
>   and stroke property values. However, the word "different" explicitly
>   specifies a value for ‘text-decoration’; thus, its underline is
>   rendered using the fill and stroke properties as the ‘tspan’ element
>   that surrounds the word "different" (i.e., yellow fill, darkgreen
>   stroke)

There's some clarification of fill/stroke but nothing on font size. Does this mean this is left up to implementors' decision? Is this defined/explained anywhere else?

Comment: Firefox does the right thing according to the CSS specification and the wrong thing according to the SVG specification. If there are inconsistencies the CSS specification will generally win in Firefox. Not sure that the others are right by any specification really.

Comment: Yeah, I came across similar comment by Boris — http://stackoverflow.com/a/10907588/130652

Comment: Also if check the strike line, you will notice that firefox render it slightly above half font, while chrome slightly below.